# Is it possible to update a column in an SQL table from a .csv file by matching one of the columns?

Tags: sql, csv

Is it possible to update a column within an SQL table with values from a csv file, by matching one of the columns?

For example:

Let's say the table that needs to be updated looks like this:

```
| Name    | Email|
| ------- | ---- |
| John    |      |
| Elroy   |      |
| Tim     |      |
```

Then the .csv file that contains the values that need to be taken from looks something like this:

```
| Name   | Email            |
| ------ | ---------------- |
| Elroy  | elroy@domain.com |
|  John  | john@gmail.com   |
| Tim    | tim@domain.co.uk |
```

So the requirements are to iterate through the csv file and where the value in the Name column matches, update the Email column in the SQL table with that corresponding value.
Is there a way to achieve this, and perhaps by using the UI of [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin)?

This is what I'm trying to do, but I don't necessarily want to merge them together, rather than update the values

```
SELECT
 *
  FROM left l
   LEFT JOIN right r
    ON l.name = r.name;
```

Comment: Yes, that's certainly possible, you would probably want to join the two data sets.

Answer (score 0):

No. But it is not too difficult to import data and update one table with the content of another one.

You'll likely benefit from diving into SSIS, there is a ui to do such things:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver16

so but if you don't like UI, i'd recommend first loading the file then du and update with a where between the imported data and your destination. Like example below.

Personally i'd use a higher level programming language like C# to be able to control edge cases better and give ui, because most likely we'll want to tell somebody about if data is crap.

If i was forced to use TSQL only, something along these lines af follows.

Example using TSQL:
To load a CSV file into a table from T-SQL, you can use the BULK INSERT statement. Here's an example:

Create a table in your SQL Server database that matches the structure of the CSV file.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Age INT
);
```

Ensure that the CSV file exists and is accessible from the SQL Server instance. You may need to place the file in a location that SQL Server can access.

Use the BULK INSERT statement to load the CSV data into the table. Here's an example:

```
BULK INSERT MyTable
FROM 'C:\path\to\your\file.csv'
WITH (
    FIRSTROW = 2,  -- Skip the header row if present
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  -- Specify the field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'  -- Specify the row terminator
);
```

In this example, replace 'C:\path\to\your\file.csv' with the actual path to your CSV file. Adjust the FIELDTERMINATOR and ROWTERMINATOR options based on the structure of your CSV file. The FIRSTROW option is used to skip the header row if present.

After executing the BULK INSERT statement, the data from the CSV file will be loaded into the MyTable table in the database.
Make sure you have the necessary permissions to execute the BULK INSERT statement and access the file location. Also, ensure that the column order and data types in the table match the structure of the CSV file.

rest is trivial i suppose once you have two table ? if not do comment i'd be happy to share

// update: added one implementation using the elements

So obviously once you have data in the import table you could apply whatever paradigm you would want for updating, here I choose that if present in import i must update, and if new i will add and if not there i will leave be.

Obviously transact sql is really old and clunky so basically you get to have a hammer and a nail so that will have to do for everything, ain't pretty and obviously should be upgraded with indexes for sure, but in quick draft could be:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'PeopleTable')
BEGIN
 CREATE TABLE PeopleTable(
    Name NVARCHAR(25),
    Email NVARCHAR (60)
 );
END

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'PeopleTableImport')
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE PeopleTableImport;
end
CREATE TABLE PeopleTableImport(
    Name NVARCHAR(25),
    Email NVARCHAR (60)
    );

BULK INSERT dbo.PeopleTableImport
FROM 'C:\path\to\your\file.csv'
WITH (
    FIRSTROW = 1,  -- Skip the header row if present
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  -- Specify the field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'  -- Specify the row terminator
);
DECLARE @active table( 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(25)
    )
-- some update logics
--Already existing must be fine in newest form
INSERT INTO @active
(
    Name
)
(SELECT [name] FROM dbo.PeopleTable WHERE name IN (SELECT [Name] FROM dbo.PeopleTableImport))

DELETE FROM dbo.PeopleTable WHERE Name IN (SELECT name FROM @active)

INSERT INTO dbo.PeopleTable
(
    Name,
    Email
)
(SELECT [Name], Email FROM dbo.PeopleTableImport x WHERE exists (SELECT y.Name FROM @active y WHERE y.Name = x.Name ))

-- then the new ones
INSERT INTO dbo.PeopleTable
(
    Name,
    Email
)
(SELECT [Name], Email FROM dbo.PeopleTableImport x WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT y.Name FROM @active y WHERE y.Name = x.Name ))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

I've created another table using the csv file.

his is what I'm trying to do, but I don't neccessarily want to merge them together, rather than update the values

SELECT 
 *
  FROM left l
   LEFT JOIN right r
    ON l.name = r.name;

Comment: There are several ways to solve this, i'll update with one suggestion.
One problematic aspect is the lack of an ID column though. it seems like name would be something people might update and this you cannot catch if you do not include this complexity. Is this just a simplificaiton for the stackoverflow?

Comment: I understand your concern. The first table that contains the majority of the data has an id column, the second one doesn't, as the data is not related directly to each other. That's why I can only use the name as a common denominator between those two

Comment: This answer looks like a substantial segment of it was written by ChatGPT

Comment: @DavidW actually section from "Create a table in your SQL Server database that matches" to "table match the structure of the CSV file." was, a quick way to give a simple example and that could have been enough :) when You chose to mention it, is that because you think of using this tool for fillers is somehow not good?